# Haskell - types/pattern matching

Tags: haskell, types, pattern-matching

the following code does not compile. I get a type error. I thought this would be the nicer version, as it clearly seperates the two different cases...
The function is supposed to help decide whether a Finite State Machine accepts an input word.

```
import Text.Show.Functions
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import qualified Data.List as List

setTransition :: (Int -> Char -> [Int])  -> [Int] -> Char -> [Int]
setTransition delta [] sigma            = []
setTransition delta xs@[x:xs'] sigma    = foldl f [] xs
                where f ys q = (delta q sigma) `List.union` ys
```

This (removed the patternmatching) however does compile. Can somebody tell me why??

```
import Text.Show.Functions
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import qualified Data.List as List

setTransition :: (Int -> Char -> [Int])  -> [Int] -> Char -> [Int]
setTransition delta [] sigma            = []
setTransition delta xs sigma    = foldl f [] xs
                where f ys q = (delta q sigma) `List.union` ys
```

Thx for helping

Comment: `xs@(x:xs')`, not `xs@[x:xs']`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just had a syntax error:

```
xs@[x:xs']
```

should be

```
xs@(x:xs')
```

But you don't actually need two cases, because

```
foldl f b [] = b
```

so

```
foldl f [] [] = []
```

just as your empty list case requires.

In fact, it's quite uncommon to pattern match on `[]` without pattern matching on `(x:xs)` and using `x` and `xs` -- that's how I knew to think about whether `foldl` would give you the right answer in both cases.  It does happen occasionally, though.